# FOS UserBundle Allow certain roles for a firewall

Tags: symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOS UserBundle in my Symfony 3.3 Project and I have two firewalls , because Admins and Users connect from different login forms (with different URLs).
I would like to restrict access to admin dashboard only if the account used for logging is granted to ADMIN_ROLE. 
That is, if I try to authenticate with a simple user account, I get the message "Bad credentials".
Is there a way to tell a firewall to only allow users of a certain role to connect ?

my security.yml firewalls section :

```
firewalls:
    admin:
        pattern:            ^/admin
        form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            login_path:     /admin
            check_path:     /admin/login_check
            default_target_path: /admin
            success_handler: app.security.adminauthentication_handler
            failure_handler:  app.security.adminauthentication_handler
        logout:
            path:           /admin/logout
            target:         /admin
        anonymous:        true
        context:          application
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            success_handler: app.security.authentication_handler
            failure_handler:  app.security.authentication_handler
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
```

Please note that I'm using AJAX for both login forms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just add this in your security.yml under security like this :

```
> security :
       access_control :
             - { path: ^/mysite/dashboard/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define [access_control](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html)